# Add multiple columns to the table based on the another column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns.
For each id we have as many as 400 `index` values. I want to add columns based on the number of index. In the example which I provide, I have 4 index, then I add four columns to the table. Here is the table I have:

```
Create table  buy_sell (id int, idx varchar(255), sell float(2, 1));

insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('1', 'a',  '4');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('1', 'b',  '6');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('1', 'c',  '8');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('1', 'd',  '9');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('3', 'b ', '1');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('3', 'c ', '2');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('2', 'a',  '5');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('2', 'b',  '7');
insert into buy_sell (id, idx,  sell) values ('2', 'd',  '5');
SELECT * FROM buy_sell;
```

Here is the result:

| id | idx | sell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 4.0 |
| 1 | b | 6.0 |
| 1 | c | 8.0 |
| 1 | d | 9.0 |
| 3 | b | 1.0 |
| 3 | c | 2.0 |
| 2 | a | 5.0 |
| 2 | b | 7.0 |
| 2 | d | 5.0 |

So, for example for id=1, we have four index here (a, b, c, d) and then we have four non-zero columns. For id = 3, we have two index (b, c), then we have two non-zero columns, so for column 1, we put zero, for column 2 we put the 1, and for column 3 we put the 2. And so on. Here is the table that I want:

| id | sell1 | sell2 | sell3 | sell4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 5 |

I searched a lot, and tried `Group_concat`, `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, etc, but I can't find out how to solve this. What do I need to do?

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Comment: @ergestBasha Thanks. However, in the provided link, there is a limited index and it is easy to use the when case. Here I have 400 index.

Comment: See how I edited the question to use formatted tables instead of screenshots? Please understand that **screenshots of data area really bad here.** Please do it this way from now on. Using copy/paste tools it shouldn't take any longer than posting the screenshot, and will make it much more likely you get a fast and accurate answer.

Comment: @joelCoehoorn Thanks you so much. Yes. now is very clear. I will do that.

Comment: @Cheese -- as you can see you are getting the same answers I gave you in your prior question.  My point is still the same -- if this is really what your data looks like what is the application for a table with 400 columns?  How exactly are you going to use this result?  There is probably a better way to do it if we know the answer to that question.

Comment: @hogan: for each id, I have 3 features. The other two features are provided in the tables with 400 columns. So, I want to build the same table as the other two feature. I am new to this area and with high probablity, I am doing a non-efficient way.

Comment: @Cheese -- I don't understand, it is not 3 features if there are 400 of them.  Sounds like 402 features to me.

Comment: @Hogan No. Each feature has 400 column. This table is only for one feature.

Comment: in any case here is an example of how to write dynamic SQL which is the only way to solve this problem as presented -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11406571/215752 (this is 12 years old, so don't expect SQL to change to make doing this easier.)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL language has a *very strict requirement* for you to know the number of columns in the results at query compile time, **before looking at any data.** If you have to look at data to find how many columns you want, you're stuck using (potentially dangerous) dynamic SQL, over three steps:

1. Run a query to find information about the desired columns.
2. Build a new SQL statement on the fly using the results from step 1.
3. Run the SQL from step 2.

In this case, you don't know how many columns you need, except that it's "Up to 400". With that in mind, you're looking at something like this:

```
SELECT ID, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN IDX = 'a' THEN sell ELSE 0 END) as sell1, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN IDX = 'b' THEN sell ELSE 0 END) as sell2, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN IDX = 'c' THEN sell ELSE 0 END) as sell3,
     -- ... 
     MAX(CASE WHEN IDX = '??' THEN sell ELSE 0 END) as sell400
FROM `buy_sell`
GROUP BY ID
```

Yes, you really do need to specify something in the query for every potential column. This also assumes all your `sell` values are greater than 0. If you could have a mix of positive and negative values you can try `SUM()` instead of `MAX()`.

This kind of thing is also in direct opposition to the Set Theory principles behind relational databases, such that in practice you're generally much better off letting your client code or reporting tool pivot the data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but your inserts for 3 have extra spaces, so fix that. And, I just noticed that you could have 400 indexes, so probably not a good approach.

```
select ID, max(CASE when IDX = 'a' then sell else 0 end) as sell1, 
     MAX(CASE when IDX = 'b' then sell else 0 end) as sell2, 
     MAX(CASE when IDX = 'c' then sell else 0 end ) as sell3, 
     MAX(CASE when IDX = 'd' then sell else 0 end ) as Sell4
from buy_sell
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks. As you mentioned, this works for small example.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a solution which is basic SQL, which adjusts for all columns thanks to a sub-query `SELECT DISTINCT`. The alignment of columns is dependent on the format of the values but we can further control that with something like

```
LEFT(CONCAT('00',sell),6)
```

if bigger numbers are involved.

> ```
> select 
>   i.idx,
>   group_concat(coalesce(
>   bs.sell,'   ')
>   order by s.sell 
>   separator '|'  ) 
>   sells 
> from
>   (select distinct sell
>   from buy_sell order by sell)s
> cross join
>   (select distinct idx 
>   from buy_sell)i
> left join buy_sell bs
> on s.sell=bs.sell
> and i.idx=bs.idx
> group by i.idx
> order by i.idx;
> ```
>
> ```
> idx | sells                          
> :-- | :------------------------------
> a   |    |   |4.0|5.0|   |   |   |   
> b   | 1.0|   |   |   |6.0|7.0|   |   
> c   |    |2.0|   |   |   |   |8.0|   
> d   |    |   |   |5.0|   |   |   |9.0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=11d51890209739da1be76908393c30d8)*